# how to retrieve data from curl -d command in python

Tags: python, curl

I need to implement a python script that acts as a server that handles data in the given format:

```
$ curl  -d "longitude=-2&latitude=4" http://localhost:8080
```

This script will interpret the longitude and latitude data in such a way as to return where this specific data falls. For another example with potential output would look something like this:

```
  $ ./state-server &
  [1] 21507
  $ curl  -d "longitude=-2&latitude=4" http://localhost:8080/
  ["Kentucky"]
  $
```

How would I access these variables within my script file?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You could use subprocess to get the output.

```
from subprocess import check_output
out = check_output(["curl",  "-d ","longitude=-77.036133&latitude=40.513799" ,"http://localhost:8080/"])
```

If you want to pass the lat and long as args:

```
lat, lon  = ....
out = check_output(["curl",  "-d ","longitude={}&latitude={}".format(lat, lon) ,"http://localhost:8080/"]
```

But there are lots of ways using just python to do what you want using [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) etc... If it is json that gets returned requests can parse the json into a dict where you can access the output by key.

If you are passing in the lat and lon from the command line you can use `sys.argv`:

```
import sys

lat, lon = sys.argv[1:]
out = check_output(["curl",  "-d ","longitude={}&latitude={}".format(lat, lon) ,"http://localhost:8080/"])
```

So you run the script and pass the args like:

```
$ cat test.py 
import sys

lat, lon = sys.argv[1:]
print(lat, lon)
$ python setup.py  1234 5678
('1234', '5678')
```

Obviously passing lat and lon to check_output in your own script.

If you want to actually parse the output of the curl command to get the variables:

```
s = """[1] 21507
  $ curl  -d "longitude=-2&latitude=4" http://localhost:8080/
  ["Kentucky"]
  $"""
import re
lat = re.search("longitude=(-?\d+(.\d+)?)",s)
lon = re.search("latitude=(-?\d+(.\d+)?)",s)

print(lat.group(1), lon.group(1))
('-2', '4')
```

Comment: Just curious, are there arguements for subprocess over system? I guess that runs in the background, right? Which is probably better....

Comment: I mean how does one access these long/lat variables from within a python script.

Comment: @hownowbrowncow, what do you mean?

Comment: @rofls, there are a lot more options using subprocess and passing  a list of args instead of trying to replicate the command exactly as you would from bash etc.. is a lot easier

Comment: I think @hownowbrowncow wants something like the function I wrote, so that his script is dynamic, but I'm not sure. Sounds like the function would probably be better with `subprocess` though ;) thanks!

Comment: @hownowbrowncow, are you saying the curl command returns json?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham  I think a string to the terminal will work.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham unimportant.  All I need to know is how to manipulate these variables passed to this script.

Comment: I don't understand how I can access those variables... let's say, for completeness sake, how I would increment the latitude by 1 in the script that is accepting this request.

Comment: what script is *accepting the request*?  If you want to pass args to a script in python you could use `sys.argv` which `argv[0]` is the name of the script and from `argv[1:]` are whatever you pass to the script

Comment: @PadraicCunningham the only script in this implementation is the one accepting the curl -d parameters.

Comment: @hownowbrowncow,  where are the lat and lon being supplied from?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham the terminal.

Comment: @hownowbrowncow so python script.py lan lon?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham No it's a curl command from the terminal in the above format I believe.

Comment: @hownowbrowncow, so you actually want to parse  string?  This is getting a little confusing, add exactly what you are dealing with to your question and what you want as output.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham reformed question.

Comment: @hownowbrowncow, so you are actually trying to get -2 and 4?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham bingo.  What i'm doing with these two integers is unimportant.

Comment: Then we are talking more regex

Comment: @hownowbrowncow, I added how to parse the output, if that is not what you want then I have no idea

Answer (score 0):

Don't waste your time with curl when you have Python modules like `requests` at your fingertips

```
import requests
payload = {'longitude': '-77.036133', 'latitude': '40.513799'}
r = requests.get("http://localhost:8080/", params=payload)
txt = r.text
```

As a general practice, using the system shell from scripts should not be done unless it's unfeasible with your native scripting language. With Python it's going to be much easier to use native libraries than to use curl for this. To install the requests library, see the [requests installation doc](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/install/#install).

Comment: Let's assume that I need to handle curl commands. how do I handle them from the servers perspective?  just using sys.argv?

Comment: funny dude.. what do u mean? !!